# is it possible or necessary to build gem to target a specific platform?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to get `scheduler_daemon` going on Win7. Looks like it's got a little bug in the current gem, so I needed to pull the source code and build the gem with `gem build D:\Dev\scheduler_daemon\scheduler_daemon.gemspec`. That completed with no issues. Then I installed the gem:

```
PS>gem install .\scheduler_daemon-1.1.2.gem
Successfully installed scheduler_daemon-1.1.2
1 gem installed
```

I tried using the gem: `gem  'scheduler_daemon-1.1.2'` or also with `, :path => "./../scheduler_daemon"` in my project but when I bundle it I get:

```
Could not find gem 'scheduler_daemon-1.1.2 (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in source at ./../scheduler_daemon.
Source does not contain any versions of 'scheduler_daemon-1.1.2 (>= 0) x86-mingw32'
```

The path is correct, at least it is if the ./ refers to the path of the gemfile. So it's looking for the x86-mingw32 platform in the source and not finding it? Is this an issue in the source code for scheduler_daemon or something in how I'm building/specifying the gem?

Related, but didn't solve: [How to use Bundler with offline .gem file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271947/how-to-use-bundler-with-offline-gem-file)

Comment: Would this be useful? http://niranjansarade.blogspot.com/2011/03/installing-windows-platform-specific.html. Edit: looks like the same method than the question you linked to.