# Connection not established to Sql Server from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, git, activerecord

Trying to connect to Sql Server from Rails. Not working so far.
I was advised to add this line to the `Gemfile` (as a fix to a known bug):

```
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', git: 'https://github.com/Desarrollo-CeSPI/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git'
```

Since I have a proxy, I didn't do this but had to perform a workaround: download the zip from that link, then unzip it in the rails project in a directory called AR, in CMD I migrated inside AR and ran

```
gem build activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.gemspec
```

After this, a gem is created, called: `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12.gem` so I typed

```
gem install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12.gem.
```

Success. At this point, no reference to any adaptors in the gemfile. `rails s` is successful: `booting WEBrick,  Rails 4.1.1 starting in development on...`.

However, when I open `localhost:3000` I see a

```
ActiveRecord::Connection not Established error
```

I should mention that the database.yml file (from config) contains:

```
development:
  adapter: activerecord-sqlserver-adapter
  mode: odbc
  dsn: odbc_new
  host: localhost
  database: cms
  pool: 5
  username: gst1
  password: pwd1234!@
```

And the cms database exists, I added that user and password to it. What is missing here? Why the connection error? Oh, I also opened Control Panel (Windows 7) - Administrative tools - set up data sources (ODBC) - and added an 'odbc_new' entry with Sql Server authentication, added the user and password there, default db: cms and ran a connectivity test before completion: success.

I don't understand though why or if I really need to create and add this odbc data source there, if I specify the user and password in the database.yml file. Can you help solve this please? Many Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
I just added `adapter: sql server` to my `database.yml`. I still get the same error though. Do I have to do something to validate the change in the `database.yml` file apart from saving it? 
Should I add something to the `Gemfile` also? Do I need to add the local adaptor (called `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12.gem`) also in my `gemfile` (taken from a local drive - instead of `rubygems.org`)? I feel the error could be connected to that.

Not sure if I need to do sth like this in the gem file

```
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12.gem', :path => 'C:\Site\simple_cms\AR'
```

but if I do, running

```
C:\Sites\simple_cms>bundle install
```

gives an error afterwards:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12.gem (>= 0)
x86-mingw32' in source at C:/Sites/simple_cms/AR.
Source does not contain any versions of
'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12.gem (>= 0) x86-mingw32'`
```

UPDATE- I also tried to specify the version number like this:
`gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '3.2.12', :path => 'C:\Site\simple_cms\AR'
but again an error:

`C:\Users\acm>cd C:\Sites\simple_cms

```
C:\Sites\simple_cms>rails s
←[31mBundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    activerecord (4.1.1)

  In Gemfile:
    activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (= 3.2.12) x86-mingw32 depends on
      activerecord (= 4) x86-mingw32

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
←[0m
```

Now, After I ran a `bundle update`, another error:

```
C:\Sites\simple_cms>bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (= 3.2.12) x86-mingw32 depends on
      activerecord (= 4) x86-mingw32 depends on
        activesupport (= 4.0.0) x86-mingw32

    rails (= 4.1.1) x86-mingw32 depends on
      activesupport (4.1.1)
```

Comment: try adding `port: 3000` to your yaml

Comment: Try starting `rails console` from a terminal window, it probably will provide some more info on what is going on.

Comment: Not using `SQLServer` myself I can only provide minimal support, but judging from the [adapter docs](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter) you can do some special things to `Configure Connection`. But you probably looked at this already?

Comment: Thanks a lot Uri! Same result, though. I'm guessing it has more to do with the dsn and how or whether I write the adapter at all in database.yml.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip Patru : `C:\Sites\simple_cms>rails console
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:247:in `require': Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/activerecord-sqlser
ver-adapter_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you
use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary
adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)`

Comment: Try with just `sqlserver` as the adapter in your `database.yml`

Comment: @Samy Long code blocks in comments just look garbled. Update your question instead, things will look al lot cleaner there (and be sure to mark the sections with **Update 1**, **Upddate 2** and the like).

Comment: Thanks, everyone. Patru, I just updated my question. Appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271947/how-to-use-bundler-with-offline-gem-file) bundler seems to be picky about the gems it tries to install from a local `:path`. Could you try specifying the version number as

```
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '3.2.12', :path => 'C:\Site\simple_cms\AR'
```

I do not think your load path will be up to snuff if `bundler` thinks it cannot resolve this gem.

Comment: Thank you so much, Patru, for this. I provided another update in the original question. Unfortunately it seems to be really hard to make this work with Sql Server. The error message seems to imply that I need a previous rails version?? Not sure. I have 4.1.1. But if I install rails 4.0.0 and remove the 4.1.1 I get the 4.1.1 again automatically when running bundle install. At a loss right now.

Comment: If that happens you should fix your rails version in your `Gemfile`, I guess you should `gem 'rails', '4.0.0'` instead of just `gem 'rails'` before you `bundle install`