# Why can't Ruby's bundle install find the gem I created?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to use a Ruby gem that I created (Called "***mygem***"). But my rails application cannot find it. Can someone please advise why and how to fix it?

**Step #1**: Verify that mygem exists in my current directory:

```
$ pwd
/myDir
$ ls mygem-1.7.3.gem
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser  wheel  27136 Aug  6 11:41 mygem-1.7.3.gem
```

**Step #2**: Make sure the Gemfile says to pickup my gem from the right place:

```
$ grep mygem Gemfile
gem "mygem", :path => "/myDir"
```

**Step #3**: Do `bundle install`.
But when I do that, it says it can't find it:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from http://gems.myserver.com/...
Fetching additional metadata from http://rubygems.org/....
Fetching additional metadata from http://gems.myserver.com/..
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'mygem (>= 0) ruby' in source at /myDir.
Source does not contain any versions of 'mygem (>= 0) ruby'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the version number

```
gem "mygem", '1.7.3', :path => "/myDir"
```

Credit goes to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271947/how-to-use-bundler-with-offline-gem-file) answer